# django_rest_swagger - 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: python, django, swagger, django-rest-swagger

> Have this error while trying to autogenerate API docs for django rest
>   framework in django 2.2.4, from what I'm seeing in the logs it has something to do with the deprectation of the {% load staticfiles %}

```
templateSyntaxError at /
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
countries
i18n
l10n
log
phone
rest_framework
static
tz
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
countries
i18n
l10n
log
phone
rest_framework
static
tz

{% load i18n %}
2   {% load staticfiles %}
3   <!DOCTYPE html>
4   <html lang="en">
5   <head>
6     <meta charset="UTF-8">
7     <title>Swagger UI</title>
8     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700|Source+Code+Pro:300,600|Titillium+Web:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
9     <link href="{% static 'rest_framework_swagger/bundles/vendors.bundle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
10    <link href="{% static 'rest_framework_swagger/bundles/app.bundle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
11    {% block extra_styles %}
12    {# -- Add any additional CSS scripts here -- #}
```

My urls file, it has the same format that in the django_rest_swagger documentation:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view


    schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='My API')

        urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path('api/user/', include('user.urls'),
            path('', schema_view)]
```

Comment: do you have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in your settings.installed_apps?

Comment: I just encountered this while setting up a brand new development site from scratch.  I do have `django.contrib.staticfiles` listed in my INSTALLED_APPS.  Since someone else just experienced this a couple days ago I wonder if something very recent affected this.

Comment: @ThunderHorn yes i do.

Comment: @Edwin The only customization that I have is that i specified the root for the static and media files as:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/vol/web/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/vol/web/static'

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Did this error occur after upgrade to Django 3.0?

Answer (score 32):

The problem is that `staticfiles` template tag was deprecated in Django 2.2 and is finally removed in Django 3.0

The `djagno-rest-swagger` package itself is deprecated and is no longer maintained.

Their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) recommends something like `drf-yasg`

Answer (score 19):

The library is deprecated

Quick fix(at your own risk): go to site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/templates/rest_framework_swagger/index.html

The line with {% load staticfiles %} (line 2) should be {% load static %}. You can edit it manually

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a `staticfiles.py` in the `templatetags` folder of your app and then paste this code:

```
from django import template
from django.templatetags.static import (do_static as _do_static,static as _static,)

register = template.Library()

def static(path):
    return _static(path)

@register.tag('static')
def do_static(parser, token):
    return _do_static(parser, token)'
```

into the file.

But make sure that the your app comes before `rest_framework_swagger` in the app list of your `settings.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The staticfiles template is deprecated in Django 2.2 and removed in Django 3.

We need to override the `rest_framework_swagger/index.html`.

Go to `site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/templates/rest_framework_swagger`

Copy the rest_framework_swagger folder and paste it in your own templates folder

Then replace the line 2 with `{% load static %}` in index.html

Hope it works !!

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the django-rest-swagger Module is not available in django 3.0 or more since the template static label is removed.

Please use other swagger packages, such as [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#installation)

Answer (score 0):

To get around this:

- navigate to your installation path of rest_framework_swagger, for me it's `env\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework_swagger`
- goto `templates/rest_framework_swagger` folder and change `staticfile` to `static` in your index.html

This is because {% load staticfiles %} and {% load admin_static %} were deprecated in Django 2.1, and removed in Django 3.0.

This work around solution is what you can use till we get it updated in rest_framework_swagger app.

Answer (score 0):

The django-rest-framework is using the Template Tag **staticfiles** which was used in Django 2. It was been dropped in Django 3.0, while the django-rest-frame repo is not while update. It was deprecated in 2019. I whould suggest using drf-yasg from
https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg

It preforms a similar function, to provide API docs automatically using swapper. I've used it and it seems good enough.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg#quickstart

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',  # required for serving swagger ui's css/js files
   ...
]
```